# Android: Listview cell does not show the selected casual font

Tags: java, android, listview, fonts

I tried to set the **`font`** of the textbox of my **listview cell** to `casual`(which is defined in Android Studio and selectable), by using the designer of Android Studio. I have the following code:
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lst"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then the code of the cell: listcell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
p1:minWidth="25px"
p1:minHeight="25px"
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
p1:background="#ffffffff">
<LinearLayout
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    p1:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <TextView
        p1:text="Mittelmäßig"
        p1:layout_width="385dp"
        p1:layout_height="60dp"
        p1:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        p1:textSize="18sp"
        p1:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        p1:background="#4b6df2"
        p1:paddingLeft="60dp"
        p1:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:fontFamily="casual" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I define my adapter: StimmungsAdapter.java:

```
public class StimmungsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity _context;
private ArrayList<String > stimmungen;
private int ImageId;

public StimmungsAdapter(Activity context)
{
    stimmungen = new ArrayList<String>();
    stimmungen.add("Überhaupt nicht");
    stimmungen.add("Wenig");
    stimmungen.add("Mittelmäßig");
    stimmungen.add("Ziemlich");
    stimmungen.add("Extrem");

    _context = context;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return stimmungen.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    String nt = stimmungen.get(position);
    if (view == null)
        view = _context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);

    TextView txtTitle =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtTitle.setText(nt);

    return view;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return stimmungen.size();
}
}
```

And call it in the onCreate Function of my MainActivity.java:

```
...
    StimmungsAdapter adapter = new StimmungsAdapter(this);
    ListView lst = (ListView)findViewById( R.id.lst);
    lst.setAdapter(adapter);
...
```

I have tried many things, but the cell is shown with the **default** **font**. When I create a normal `TextView`(not in a listview as cell) then the `casual` font is shown.
Why is the font not show in the listview cell?

Comment: What device are you running this on? (is it samsung?)

Comment: Yes it is Samsung. Didn't know that this makes a difference

Comment: But I don't think that this is a matter of problem. Cause if I use a normal textbox(not in a listview) then the font is shown correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `tools:fontFamily` with `android:fontFamily` (or in your case, `p1:fontFamily`)`

The problem is you have the `fontFamily` attribute prefixed with the `tools:` namespace. This makes the attribute value only apply to the layout editor preview and be discarded when compiling to an apk.

Comment: Yes, thanks it worked. The code was generated by Android Studio. Don't know why then the tools tag was inserted